# ngx treeview dropdown

Tags: css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-dropdown-treeview?

ngxDisabledOnSelector property has not working  in my case

my code here :

```
<ngx-dropdown-treeview [config]="config" [items]="items" [buttonClass]="buttonClass"
        (selectedChange)="values = $event" [disabled]="!dropdownEnabled"
        [ngxDisabledOnSelector]="'button.dropdown-toggle'" (filterChange)="onFilterChange($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

"disabled", is basically a HTML attribute, but not necessary an Input param for you ngx treeview, so, in this case you have 2 options.

1.- Use disable as angular html attribute

```
[attr.disabled]="!dropdownEnabled"
```

2.- Use direct attribute

```
disabled="{{!dropdownEnabled}}"
```

lets try